# PHP array_combine if not null

Tags: php, arrays, array-combine

I want to combine data only if value is exist. example:

```
// array 1
array:4 [▼
  0 => "qwfd"
  1 => "qw2e3"
  2 => null
  3 => null
]
// array 2
array:4 [▼
  0 => "qwef"
  1 => "w2"
  2 => null
  3 => null
]
```

I need to ignore `2=>` and `3=>` in both arrays as they are null.

`Ps` Even if one of them is null also needs to be ignored (example)

```
// array 1
array:4 [▼
  0 => "qwfd"
  1 => "qw2e3"
  2 => "i am here"
  3 => null
]
// array 2
array:4 [▼
  0 => "qwef"
  1 => "w2"
  2 => null
  3 => null
]
```

In this case array `1`, `2=>` has value but because array `2`, `2=>` doesn't. It shouldn't be combined either.

`My code`

```
$names = $request->input('social_media_name'); // array 1
$usernames = $request->input('social_media_username'); // array 2
$newArray = array_combine($names, $usernames);
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward. Loop and check if values at indexes are null. If either of them are, skip it, else set the key and value pair.

```
<?php 

$result = [];

foreach($names as $index => $val){
  if (is_null($val) || is_null($usernames[ $index ]) continue;
  $result[ $val ] = $usernames[ $index ];
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter` to filter out the array that return only if `$name, $username` are not null. Or even if one of them is null also not be returned.

```php
$names = [0 => "qwfd",1 => "qw2e3",2 => "i am here",3 => null];
$usernames = [0 => "qwef",1 => "w2",2 => null,3 => null];

$newArray = array_combine($names, $usernames);
$newArray = array_filter($newArray,
              fn($name, $username)=>!is_null($name) and
                     !is_null($username),ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($newArray);
```

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [qwfd] => qwef
    [qw2e3] => w2
)
```